# can any one suggest me how to use sikuli in cucumber maven?

Tags: java, sikuli

I am getting the error for sikuli constructor: cannot initiate the type screen[here org.sikuli.api.Screen is imported but failing to initiate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUffW.png)

In pom.xml i have used the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How is the question related to `selenium`?

Comment: sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependency it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. POM is throwing error.